# How to press Generate Data Layers button

Tags: python

Any ideas how to press Generate Data Layers button from DataTransfer modifier in python? Can't find it in documentation: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.DataTransferModifier.html

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]

with bpy.context.temp_override(object=obj):
    bpy.ops.object.datalayout_transfer(modifier="DataTransfer")
```

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.datalayout_transfer

Comment: Wow it works, thank you. This is very unobvious thing